# How to retrieve the CNAME records of a custom domain name in blogger

Tags: domains, blogger

I added a custom domain to my blogger account some time ago, and updated the CNAME records in the domain registrar, and everything worked fine.

Few weeks ago, I transferred the domain from the old registrar to a new one.

Now, I'm faced with having to connect the custom domain to work with the blogger address, as it used to work.

I've tried to delete the domain name and enter it again, but it is not bringing any CNAME records. I've also tried to use another domain name, and use the CNAME records that it brought, but the custom domain is not working either.

Is there a way I can reset the details of the custom domain entry from blogger?

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after so many failed attempts, I found out that during the transfer of the domain, the nameserver from the previous registrar was still being used in the new registrar.

So, what I did was to update the nameserver of the domain to point to the new registrar's default nameservers, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the CNMAE records is regenerated every time you change the domain name.

You say you've tried switching it to another domain and use the record for that, but it doesn't work.    If you've tried to use the other domain's records for your desired domain, then I'm not surprised that it didn't verify.

Depending on what you have now, then maybe try deleting the custom domain and waiting 24 hours for the change to propogate fully.     (Am guessing that your custom domain isn't currently working anyway, so this won't make things any worse.)

Otherwise, post in the Blogger help forum, and keep bumping the question until one of the TC's there sees it and helps.   It may be that Blogger has a defect in this area, and hasn't considered that people may change domain registrars and need the CNAMES to transfer.

Comment: Okay, I'll try your suggestion to delete and wait. I'll let you know what happens next.

Comment: Still didn't work. And I think I was able to find the solution. I'll put it as an answer.